# CSS cross-browser issue

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm making a numbers game for people studying English as a second language. It's using a WordPress plugin that uses HTML5 and, as a fallback, Flash -- this will be important for me because many target users of my game will be in Asia where older browsers are used.  The game involves 16 audio tracks that are all invisible on the page and one random one will be made visible via javascript fade in once the user clicks the start button.

**Problem:** In Chrome and Safari, the audio player is successfully hidden via CSS `display: none`.  However, in my Firefox 5, the browser is (for some reason unknown to me, but it's good that this problem has arisen) using the Flash playeer and the styles are not applying to it, so there's 16 audio players on the screen in Firefox.

This is the CSS I am using.

Do you know a way to make this CSS apply to the flash player as well? The 16 audio tracks have ids from 1 - 16

```
#ONE, #TWO, #THREE, #FOUR, #FIVE, #SIX, #SEVEN, #EIGHT, #NINE, #TEN, #ELEVEN, #TWELVE, #THIRTEEN, #FOURTEEN, #FIFTEEN, #SIXTEEN {position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none; }
```

This is a link to the game. Note, the game is unfinished so don't expect to play it. Right now you can only see the CSS problem depending on your browser.

[NumbersGame](http://eslangel.com/66-2/)

Comment: not knowing the whole situation, I can think of - "why dont you put all those players in a div and add ``display:none`` style to the div instead?

Comment: @LocusHorde all those players are in a div, but if I apply display:none to that div, can I still randomly select and make visible one of the players via javascript?

Comment: oh, hm, in that case you might need each player in a div with unique id (whatever is better. like something you can link to player and div)  but if you are generating it all dynamically in the same page, may be there are better solutions below.

Answer (score 0):

behavior confirmed on Firefox 3 too.

Here what i see with firebug on the 5th audio:

```
<div style="">
 <object id="f-FIVE" width="290" height="24" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"         name="f-FIVE" style="outline: medium none; visibility: visible;" data="http://eslangel.com /wp-content/plugins/degradable-html5-audio-and-video/incl/player.swf">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="flashvars" value="initialvolume=80&soundFile=http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/five.mp3&playerID=f-FIVE">
</object>
```

We can see that the style of your object id="f-FIVE" is visibility=visible.

If you change it to hidden the control is hidden.

Comment: Just might saw the problem...  you CSS is trying to apply a style on element #FIVE... but the real element id is #f-FIVE.  If you dont have firebug for firefox.  I would suggest getting it ;-) very helpfull in those situation.  good day

Comment: No, its not the problem - the problem is, that for some reason all payers has added 'style' attribute, that overrides css rules.

Comment: the real element is #f-FIVE only with the flash player. With the html5 player, the id is #FIVE, which is the id I gave it. So do I need to create two style sheets? Can I do some kind of contingent style sheet for use with a flash player?

Comment: Well from what i understand, it is a plugin who generate html5 player or flash player depending on the browser capability?...  if so, you have to find a way to tweek the generation of the flash player to not include styling, because even if you stytle the f-FIVE element in a CSS, the style attribute inline will override your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using the HTML5 DOCTYPE.

Secondly, you seem to be serving MP3 files only which aren't supported by Firefox, which only supports OGG.

Using Firebug I can see that none of the many divs surrounding the Flash player actually has `display:none` set at all.

Comment: o.k, thanks for pointing out the Firefox mp3 issue, but my firefox browswer is playing the mp3 (with flash) so I don't understand what you're getting at... Are you suggesting that if I use OGC, then I won't have this problem? or what?  I'm a newbie developer (actually just a teacher trying to make something) so please explain more if you can.    Regarding your third point, you have basically repeated the problem I state in the OP. The CSS styles aren't applying to the flash player, so how can I make that happen?

Comment: How are you deciding whether to serve HTML5 or Flash, or is the plugin doing it for you? Regarding the styling, the display:none style is not being applied, as the ids you are applying it to don't seem to be in the code when viewing it through Firefox 5. e.g. each player is being surrounded by a div with the CSS classes: "audio_wrap" and "html5audio" - applying display:none to these, hides them. But, since I don't know what logic you or your code is using to decide which ones to show and hide, it's difficult to say exactly where to apply it.

Comment: the plugin's deciding HTML5 or Flash. All the players are supposed to be hidden at the start. They are going to be in an array and one of them chosen randomly from the array and made visible.  The jquery logic for choosing the random key from the array is basically what you see at this fiddle except there will be sixteen elements in the array rather than the 3 colors that are in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urfXq/96/

Comment: Firefox does not support MP3 files, but you can still play mp3 files with a polyfill like jquery mediaelements.js - http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each `<!-- degradable html5 audio and video plugin -->` line there is some JavaScript that looks like this:

```
if (jQuery.browser.mozilla) {tempaud=document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0]; jQuery(tempaud).remove(); jQuery("div.audio_wrap div").show()} else jQuery("div.audio_wrap div *").remove();
```

Which seems to be saying that if the browser is mozilla, then it should show the div that you have set to `display:none`.  What was you intention for this bit of code?

Comment: You might want to remove it and see what happens, because it is saying that if the browser identifies as mozilla, which Firefox does, then the `display:none` that is set to each of these divs will be removed by the `show()` function call.

Comment: it appears to need that code. I removed it and tried to show 1 player which is visible in Chrome now, but not in Firefox.